# AnyLogic - dropoff block - Can I combine "while condition is true" and "given quantity"?

Tags: anylogic

I am wondering how I can combine "while condition is true" and "given quantity" at the same time, regarding AnyLogic dropoff block.

The following chart is working well. While condition (agent.aclass == true) is true, element agent (Cargo) are dropped off. For your reference, Cargo has a bool parameter (aclass or !aclass) .

However, my problem is that **"all available element agents are dropped off"**. I would like to specify a certain quantify (for example, 1, 2, or whatever) to be dropped off, keeping the condition "while condition is true".

Would you help me?

[image]

All agents are dropped off even though I want to specify the quantity to be dropped off.

Comment: What is your Pickup logic? They should be the same/similar (or even better drop all)...if you are picking up different amount, then you will have items waiting inside dropoff for a long time which doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: Dear Yashar, thank you for  your comment.
1. Element agents (Cargo) are generated. Boolean parameter generates 2 types of Cargo agent (aclass or !aclass) .
2. Generated Cargo agent makes queue on FIFO basis.
3. Element agent (Cargo) is picked up by container agent (mobile rack).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Dropoff block doesn't support what you want directly, since the dropoff 'protocol' can only be "All available" *or* "Specified number" *or* "While condition is true".

## Easy solution

The easy way to get round it is to incorporate the 'have I dropped off beyond my threshold?' check into the condition.

So you would

- Maintain a count (via an `int` Variable called, say, `numDroppedOffThisBatch`) of the number currently dropped off in the current 'batch', reset when the agent enters the Dropoff block ("On enter" action).
- Change your Dropoff while condition to be `agent.classA && (numDroppedOffThisBatch++ < 2)` if, say, your threshold was 2.

That is, you only dropoff it it's a class A cargo **and** the number you have previously dropped off for this carrier agent is less than the threshold. The `++` *after* the variable name is a postfix operator in Java, which means it only increments the variable *after* it has been used in the expression. (So it does represent the number *already* dropped off.) You could equally have used `++numDroppedOffThisBatch <= 2` but the variable name is a bit misleading then.

## Overly-complex but interesting alternative

Another option is as below, which effectively 'instantly re picks-up' (i.e., in zero sim time) the agents that shouldn't really have been dropped off. This is much more complex but is an interesting approach to understand (and similar things are useful in other contexts), so I've left it in...

It's tricky because you have to understand some under-the-covers details of the order in which things happen with a Dropoff block. Basically, **dropped-off agents have their "On dropoff" actions run *and* are sent to their next block *before* the carrier agent leaves the Dropoff block**. This actually makes things easier for us since we know we can 'initially process' dropped-off agents before the carrier agent leaves. So, we

- Dropoff using the while condition as currently, but then have the dropping-off agent go into Pickup block (set to pickup "All available agents") *and* the dropped-off agents go into a Select Output block which goes either to a Queue (attached to the Pickup block via its special port) or its normal current destination (which looks like a MoveTo block from your (tiny!) screenshot).
- Maintain a count (via an `int` Variable called, say, `numDroppedOffThisBatch`) of the number currently dropped off in the current 'batch', reset when the agent enters the Dropoff block ("On enter" action) and incremented as the dropped-off agents are dropped-off ("On dropoff" action) which is *before* they actually leave the block or test the following SelectOutput condition.
- Also maintain another count variable `numProcessedThisBatch` (also reset to zero when the carrier agent enters the Dropoff block).
- Agents dropped off then go into a SelectOutput which, if `numProcessedThisBatch` is **greater than or equal to** your 'how many should really have been dropped off' threshold, get routed to the Queue; otherwise they carry on as normal. (Note we are **not** checking `numDroppedOffThisBatch` here, which will always be the total number dropped off at this point.)
- When a dropped-off agent enters the Queue *or* MoveTo blocks (i.e., when it finishes 'processing' either way), increment `numProcessedThisBatch`.

Below is a sample process flow screenshot (note the meaningful naming of blocks). The bit outside the red box is just stuff I added to setup a carrier agent with a mixture of class A and non-class-A Cargo agents via the buttons (and I just represented the 'follow on' flows for the carrier and should-actually-have-been-dropped-off cargo agents as nominal Delay blocks).

[image: Sample test process flow]

Here I had the carrier agent contain 3 class-A cargo agents and 2 non-class-A one, with a threshold of 2 agents to 'actually' dropoff (which I held in a variable for clarity).

To make the sequencing clearer (and to show how everything occurs at the same sim time), below are some `traceln` console messages produced which help understand what's happening. (The ones after I manually set up the carrier via the buttons are prefixed with the simulation time.)

```
Creating cargo class A agent
Creating cargo class A agent
Creating cargo class A agent
Creating cargo non-class-A agent
Creating cargo non-class-A agent
Creating carrier agent
6.699999999999991: carrier dropping off cargo agents by condition
6.699999999999991: cargo On dropoff action
6.699999999999991: cargo On dropoff action
6.699999999999991: cargo On dropoff action
6.699999999999991: Cargo agent starting normal process: class A true
6.699999999999991: Cargo agent starting normal process: class A true
6.699999999999991: Cargo agent ready for instant pickup: class A true
6.699999999999991: Carrier agent entering post-dropoff pickup
```

**Notes**:

1. It would also be a lot better to then encapsulate all this dropoff-by-condition-and-number logic into a custom block which you can then reuse wherever you want it (and avoid polluting the main process-containing agent with variables). That's obviously another level of detail and complexity.
2. This behaviour of the Dropoff block with a following SelectOutput is actually quite subtle. SelectOutput block conditions are evaluated *before* agents actually leave the previous block. (Because SelectOutputs are just routing decisions, they aren't really 'part' of the flow, in the sense that agents spend no time there; think of them as being used to say 'Where should I go next when I leave the preceding block?'.) That is why many blocks (like Delay) have "On exit" and "On at exit" actions. (The latter runs *before* AnyLogic even tries to see what block it should go to next, so will happen before a following SelectOutput check.) It just happens that Dropoff blocks run their "On dropoff" actions *before* checking what the onward block might be; thus they function in the same way as "On at exit" actions in other blocks.

Comment: Dear Stuart, thank you very much for your great detailed support! I tried your recommended Easy Solution at first and it has worked well! Anyway, I would like to say thank you! Please let me think about well your logic for my further understanding!